# Move-to-Trash functionality

Tags: android

On the frontpage you can drag icons to the trash by pressing them for a few seconds, the trash pops up and you move them out of the way. Is it possible to implement this functionality to my own application? Meaning I want to press on a shape in a my drawing view and then move this shape into the trash and remove it from my drawing queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get the readymade thing for your requirement but visit links below so that you will get the idea and guideline how to achieve your goal.

[DragDropArticle](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)

[Step By Step Guide](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/)

[Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

I tried my best ....